# Реализовать удаление каждого второго элемента коллекции

Tags: java

Возникла проблема при написании кода. Считываю при помощи сканера элементы, добавляю их в коллекцию до момента прерывания записи. Завел переменную `i` для того, чтобы не записывать каждый второй элемент в коллекцию. Но данная запись не работает.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayDeque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

    int value;
    int i = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        value = scanner.nextInt();
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            queue.add(value);
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(queue);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того как `i` станет равно `1`, код внутрь `if` никогда не попадет.

Надо

```
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        queue.add(value);
    }
    i++;
```

или

```
    if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
        queue.add(value);
    }
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. А почему переменная `i` не обновлялась в при вызове в `if`?

Comment: @AlexLynch Потому что, после того как она станет равна `1`, Вы в этот `if` никогда не попадете.

Comment: я бы не заводил переменную I в принципе. она только путает вас. boolean проще и удобнее :     boolean needWrite=true;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        if (needWrite) queue.add(value);
        needWrite=!needWrite;
    }